# Xamarin, ExpandableListView What should I do?

Tags: xamarin, expandablelistview

How do I put a different event on a child?

( For example )
1. Group
 - Child ( Switch )
 - Child ( Button )
 - Child ( SeekBar )

What should I do?
Please let me know if you have examples where you can see

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question and give more information and a better example. Also add what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try searching for something like "apply event to views in side viewcell in xamarin forms". This may point you in right direction.

Here is a example link for xamarin forms:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73470/detecting-tap-on-label-inside-viewcell-inside-listview